# Acces server source file from another PC with PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, project, remote-server

I don't know if someone has done this before,

but I would like to split my server and editor.

By that I mean that I want to be on my Windows PC, editing the code using PhpStorm and sending command to my Linux server via SSH.

The Linux server would be another machine connected to my local network, it should run the web server and I want to be able to edit files from my Windows PC using PhpStorm.

Do you know a way of doing this? Something as transparent as if the web server was on the same Windows machine. I've tried using "Deployment > FTP" but it's not great for this kind of use.

Comment: What's bad with the FTP option?

Comment: @Alejandro It's not smooth, if I run a command on the server I need to sync on the client, if I switch branch too

Comment: Share the code on a linux machine over the network, then mount that folder in Windows as a network disc. You can then add this folder to your project in PhpStorm as include path at File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP, or even open it directly. That's not recommended though, but that would work

Comment: The *Create New Project* wizard has two options that start with "Web server is on remote host". I guess those are basically your options.

Comment: @Dmitrii mhhh I like the idea I'll try thanks !

Comment: @Dmitrii well it works perfectly for me, thanks !

Comment: Great! Happy to help